# Set URL of "like" button embedded in Facebook comments plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, facebook-like, xfbml

How can I set the URL of the "like" button embedded in the Facebook comments plugin?

The XFBML [<fb:like>](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) tag has an `href` attribute, but the [<fb:comments>](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_%28XFBML%29) tag lacks an equivalent attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated for new version of Facebook comments plugin:**

The new Facebook comments plugin no longer uses the `xid` attribute. Instead, the `href` attribute is used to both identify the comments box and associate a URL with it.

Compare [new <fb:comments>](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to [legacy <fb:comments>](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments/)

---

*original answer:*

Figured it out while asking the question:

The `<fb:comments>` *`url` attribute* works like the `<fb:like>` `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The *url* attribute seems to be deprecated. There are two new attributes *returnurl* and *callbackurl* but they have no effect on the LIKE url. Maybe it's a question of time, I don't know. I cretaed a new app, changed the *og:url* attribute but still no luck. It keeps on "liking" the same page.